# thymeleaf - how to load image from absolute path

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

On thymeleaf, its possible to load image from absolute path in img tag

```
<img alt="" src="/home/sahmada/Documents/workspace/myapp/src/main/resources/static/images/image01.jpg" />
```

I use Spring boot + thymeleaf

Comment: It's not related to thymeleaf, it's the same as using any other template view engine, in order to access some image or any other file, you have to serve the resources from Spring, check: http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: thanks Patrick LC, your advice is work.

I add this code on my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/foto/**").addResourceLocations("file:///home/sahmada/Desktop/images/");

 }